# Counter not working

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to do some grouping with the usage of counters, such that it will increment accordingly.. I apologize if my title gives the wrong impression but...

Anyway, when I have 2 or more selections and as I execute my code, instead of seeing groups with naming such as - TEST_1_GRP, TEST_2_GRP, TEST_3_GRP etc., I am getting TEST_1_GRP, TEST_1_GRP1, TEST_1_GRP2 as my results...

I tried placing some of the line for the counter portion around (like within/ before the for sentence), I am getting nowhere..

Below is my code:

```
def fix_shapes():
    all_geos = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    for geo in all_geos:
        shapes = cmds.listRelatives(geo, fullPath=True, shapes=True)

        if len(shapes) == 1:
            continue

        new_listing = []
        listing.append(shapes[:1])
        # pop out the first shape, since we don't have to fix it
        multi_shapes = shapes[1:]
        for multi_shape in multi_shapes:
            new_transform = cmds.duplicate(multi_shape, parentOnly=True)
            new_geos = cmds.parent(multi_shape, new_transform, addObject=True, shape=True)
            listing.append(new_geos)


            # remove the shape from its original transform
            cmds.parent(multi_shape, removeObject=True, shape=True)

        # counter to 'version' up new_geos group naming
        counter = 0
        new_group_name = cmds.group(em=True, name = 'TEST_' + str(counter + 1) + '_GRP')

        for item in new_listing:
            counter = counter + 1
            new_geos_parent_name = cmds.listRelatives(item, parent = True)
            cmds.parent(new_geos_parent_name, new_group_name)
```

Comment: You have `counter = 0` and `str(counter + 1)` immediately afterwards. I don't know what you're expecting, but if you set a variable to 0, then check its value, you're always going to get 0. `str(counter + 1)` can't be anything but `"1"` there.

Answer (score 0):

Move your counter as follows, you aren't using the counter in your last loop so remove it from that. Check this does what you want?

```
def fix_shapes():
    all_geos = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    counter = 0
    for geo in all_geos:
        shapes = cmds.listRelatives(geo, fullPath=True, shapes=True)

        if len(shapes) == 1:
            continue

        new_listing = []
        listing.append(shapes[:1])
    # pop out the first shape, since we don't have to fix it
        multi_shapes = shapes[1:]
        for multi_shape in multi_shapes:
            new_transform = cmds.duplicate(multi_shape, parentOnly=True)
            new_geos = cmds.parent(multi_shape, new_transform, addObject=True, shape=True)
            listing.append(new_geos)


        # remove the shape from its original transform
            cmds.parent(multi_shape, removeObject=True, shape=True)

    # counter to 'version' up new_geos group naming

        new_group_name = cmds.group(em=True, name = 'TEST_' + str(counter + 1) + '_GRP')

        for item in new_listing:
            new_geos_parent_name = cmds.listRelatives(item, parent = True)
            cmds.parent(new_geos_parent_name, new_group_name)
```

Comment: Hi there, it is still not working... It is still giving me `TEST_1_GRP1` when I selected one or more items.. Not sure if this will aid, but this is my maya test [file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/glhfon16dwi1pbh/test.ma), try selecting the `ref_1_geo5` and `ref_1_geo6` and execute my code, perhaps that may give you a better idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may solve your problem. Keep in mind that the first time you execute your code, it will work as expected and produce groups named `TEST_1_GRP TEST_2_GRP` etc. However, the second time it will be named `TEST_1_GRP1 TEST_2_GRP1` etc. because you're not saving or checking if the name exists. To work around this you can either store a global variable, check during names during execution, or store the counted value in the scene file or someplace else. I'll leave this to you.

```
def fix_shapes():
    all_geos = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    counter = 0 ### moved counter outside loop
    for geo in all_geos:
        shapes = cmds.listRelatives(geo, fullPath=True, shapes=True)

        if len(shapes) == 1:
            continue

        listing = [] ### fixed naming, was new_listing, not coherent
        listing.append(shapes[:1])
        # pop out the first shape, since we don't have to fix it
        multi_shapes = shapes[1:]
        for multi_shape in multi_shapes:
            new_transform = cmds.duplicate(multi_shape, parentOnly=True)
            new_geos = cmds.parent(multi_shape, new_transform, addObject=True, shape=True)
            listing.append(new_geos)


            # remove the shape from its original transform
            cmds.parent(multi_shape, removeObject=True, shape=True)

        # counter to 'version' up new_geos group naming
        new_group_name = cmds.group(em=True, name = 'TEST_' + str(counter + 1) + '_GRP')

        counter += 1 ### simpler way to increment instead of "counter = counter + 1"

        for item in listing: ### fixed new_listing name here as well
            new_geos_parent_name = cmds.listRelatives(item, parent = True)
            cmds.parent(new_geos_parent_name, new_group_name)
```

I've marked the changes with ### with some comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fix_shapes():
    all_geos = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    counter = 0
    for geo in all_geos:
        shapes = cmds.listRelatives(geo, fullPath=True, shapes=True)

        if len(shapes) == 1:
            continue

        new_listing = []
        new_listing.append(shapes[:1])
    # pop out the first shape, since we don't have to fix it
        multi_shapes = shapes[1:]
        for multi_shape in multi_shapes:
            new_transform = cmds.duplicate(multi_shape, parentOnly=True)
            new_geos = cmds.parent(multi_shape, new_transform, addObject=True, shape=True)
            new_listing.append(new_geos)


        # remove the shape from its original transform
            cmds.parent(multi_shape, removeObject=True, shape=True)

    # counter to 'version' up new_geos group naming
        new_grp_id = "TEST_{0}_GRP".format(counter)
        if not cmds.objExists(new_grp_id):
           new_group_name = cmds.group(em=True, name = new_grp_id)
           counter += 1
        else:
           for o in reversed(xrange(100)):
               if cmds.objExists("TEST_{0}_GRP".format(o)):
                  counter = o + 1
                  break
           new_group_name = cmds.group(em=True, name = "TEST_{0}_GRP".format(counter))
           counter += 1

        for item in new_listing:
            new_geos_parent_name = cmds.listRelatives(item, parent = True)
            cmds.parent(new_geos_parent_name, new_group_name)
```

for the second iteration you need something like max range counter,
so we have build some checks .... so now it will do create grps and add items to it, by next iterations it will find the max value of "TEST_n_GRP" and increase that, think that it will find the biggest int, not the between integers, eg: in scene: grp_1 and grp_3, the next biggest number is the grp_4, but it will not find grp_2! you can remove the reversed operator, for that. 
with the reversed operator you will find really fast the biggest/last integers but not the between ints